# custom error message for bad request in jhipster project

Tags: javascript, java, css, angularjs, jhipster

I am trying to create a new Entity name if entity name is already exist i need to prompt the message.

Below is the code i have added to send error message. i am able to send the alert to dialog screen, but UI is printing as Object: object i am compare the json format success and failure i am sending the same but when success it is printing but when failure it printing has [object object]

```
@Timed
public ResponseEntity createEndpoint(@Valid @RequestBody Endpoint endpoint)         throws URISyntaxException {
log.debug("REST request to save Endpoint : {}", endpoint);
// endpoint.setId(1L);
if (endpoint.getId() != null) {
return ResponseEntity.badRequest().header("Failure", "A new endpoint cannot    already have an ID").body(null);
 }

Endpoint result =endpointRepository.findByName(endpoint.getName());
if (result!= null) {
    return ResponseEntity.badRequest().location(new URI("/api/endpoints/" + result.getId()))
    .headers(HeaderUtil.createEntityNameDuplicateAlert("Failure", result.getId().toString()))
    .body(result);

}else{
 result = endpointRepository.save(endpoint);
}
endpointSearchRepository.save(result);
return ResponseEntity.created(new URI("/api/endpoints/" + result.getId()))
        .headers(HeaderUtil.createEntityCreationAlert("endpoint", result.getId().toString()))
        .body(result);
}
```

But when i use the ResponseEntity.create method i am able to see the message in green color enitity .html .but i want display the error message in enitity dialogue box in in red color .

```
return ResponseEntity.created(new URI("/api/endpoints/" + result.getId()))
.headers(HeaderUtil.createEntityCreationAlert("endpoint", result.getId().toString()))
.body(result);
```

i tried both 
and for more information i am adding my error screen

[image]

Comment: Did you try to debug what you get in the response object headers in web console?

Comment: From your screen shot looks like you are trying to send an object instead of string, just do a debug or see in the net tab what is the response object you get in chrome console

Comment: Iam getting same response header for both success and failure, below is the success {"id":3,"name":"vi","url":null,"description":null} and failure {"id":3,"name":"vi","url":null,"description":null}                                                                            but when i user Httpstatus created i am able to display the messages but httpstatus.badrequest i am getting the above error.

Comment: càn you post your HeaderUtil.createEntityNameDuplicateAlert method?

Comment: Also post the raw http request and response