# How to enable custom UI error messages on Dialog Popups in JHipster 4.13.2

Tags: angular, jhipster

I'm loving the JHipster project, a big thank you to the team, its really a big time saver. I do however get a bit stuck on a few things. My latest issue is related to getting custom error alerts on the UI pages, specifically the dialog popups - doing create, delete, custom operations etc.

To replicate the issue, create any entity or go into the UserResource.delete() or createUser() REST function and force an exception to be thrown (changed the != to ==) the BadRequestAlertException exception as below:

```
if (userDTO.getId() == null) {
    throw new BadRequestAlertException("A new user cannot already have an 
        ID", "userManagement", "idexists");
```

I was expecting the error the show on the user-management-dialog.component.html as it has the declared tags:

```
<jhi-alert-error></jhi-alert-error>
```

But, all I got was the error in the server logs:

```
2018-02-06 15:49:17.025 ERROR 5352 --- [ XNIO-4 task-21] 
c.s.hr.oa.web.rest.util.HeaderUtil       : Entity processing failed, A new 
user cannot already have an ID

2018-02-06 15:49:17.027  WARN 5352 --- [ XNIO-4 task-21] 
o.z.p.spring.web.advice.AdviceTrait      : Bad Request: A new user cannot 
already have an ID
```

I'm obviously missing something minor here? Would really appreciate any pointers.
I was reading in other posts linked below and seems it should work. I've tried a few of the suggestions but they are based on older version of Angular and JHipster. I'm on Release 4.13.3

- [Custom JHipster Error Messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33202543/custom-error-message-for-bad-request-in-jhipster-project)
- [Alert Errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37727959/jhipster-jhi-alert-error-element-and-server-side-form-validation)

Comment: Have you checked in browser console the JSON response you got on error?

Comment: yes, the 400 BadRequest does come through as a response, with the header populated with my error message. I traced through the code and it executes via the `handleBadRequestAlertException()` method , which sets the header with the error.     `@ExceptionHandler(BadRequestAlertException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<Problem> handleBadRequestAlertException(BadRequestAlertException ex, NativeWebRequest request) {
        return create(ex, request, HeaderUtil.createFailureAlert(ex.getEntityName(), ex.getErrorKey(), ex.getMessage()));
    }`

Comment: There is a body yes. `{
  "entityName" : "userManagement",
  "errorKey" : "idexists",
  "type" : "http://www.jhipster.tech/problem/problem-with-message",
  "title" : "A new user cannot already have an ID",
  "status" : 400,
  "message" : "error.idexists",
  "params" : "userManagement"
}`

Comment: I basically just took the jhipster code as it was generated and forced an exception to see if they come through to the UI dialog popup. I haven't done anything different as yet, I'm really trying to understand the preferred way to use the in-built JHipster error mechanism so I can add some custom response errors. I cant help feeling I'm overlooking some minor detail/config or something. If we can figure it out, it could be a good item for the JHipster FAQ page.

Comment: retagged to angular, I believe the version of JHipster I am on is Angular5, apologies and thank you for the responses, it is most appreciated.

Comment: I have reproduced the issue with 4.13.2 but not with 4.14.0. So please upgrade and you should see the alert well displayed by angular code.

Comment: That's awesome news! Thank you, I will upgrade and advise shortly.

Comment: The manual upgrade has gone a bit awry:`ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/main/webapp/app/blocks/interceptor/http.provider.ts:1:27
    TS2305: Module '"../node_modules/ng-jhipster/index"' has no exported member 'JhiInterceptableHttp'.
ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/main/webapp/.../http.provider.ts:3:50
    TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/http'.
ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/main/webapp/.../http.provider.ts:23:13
    TS2554: Expected 2 arguments, but got 3.
ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/main/webapp/.../response-wrapper.model.ts:1:25
    TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/http'.
`

Comment: The auto upgrade worked much better but got these errors. I'll move this to a seperate question and what I needed to do to get it  working. `ERROR in ./src/main/webapp/app/polyfills.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'classlist.js' 
ERROR in ./src/main/webapp/app/polyfills.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'web-animations-js' 
`. I'm going to add those two deps back in for now to package.json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Auto upgrade to 4.14.0 works great, just re-add these 2 deps to the package.json

```
"web-animations-js": "^2.3.1",
"classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312"
```

The errors are now all working like a charm on the dialog popups!! Thank you!!
Great job to the JHipster devs!!

Comment: Great, I'd recommend to use exact versions "2.3.1" rather than "^2.3.1" to avoid breaking your build/app when some dep introduces breaking changes.